# Psar consulta SQL a Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo esta consulta en SQL:

```
  SELECT * FROM doc_insts 
WHERE instituto_id = 1 AND doc_insts.id NOT IN 
(
    SELECT documentacion_id FROM doc_alu_insts WHERE instituto_id = 1 AND alumno_id = 1
)
```

y debo pasarla a Laravel. E intentado pero hasta ahora no obtengo resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto

```
$intento1 = ModeloQueUsas::where('instituto_id', $instituto_id)
->whereNotIn('doc_insts',function ($q) use ($instituto_id) {
    DB::table('doc_alu_insts')->select('documentacion_id')
 ->where('instituto_id', $instituto_id)
 ->where('alumno_id', $id_alumno)
})->get();


$intento2 = DB::table('doc_insts')->where('instituto_id', $instituto_id)
->whereNotIn('doc_insts',function ($q) use ($instituto_id) {
    DB::table('doc_alu_insts')->select('documentacion_id')
 ->where('instituto_id', $instituto_id)
 ->where('alumno_id', $id_alumno)
})->get();
```

Comment: Intenté de esas dos formas, me devuelve:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. Creo que whereNotIn( ) necesita que se le pase 2 parametros y uno debe ser un array de esta forma whereNotIn( 'tabla ',[1,2,3,4] )

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solucion!

```
$instituto_id = DB::table('alumnos')->where('dni',$dni)
                  ->Join('alu_carr_insts','alumnos.id','=','alu_carr_insts.alumno_id')
                  ->pluck('alu_carr_insts.instituto_id')->first();
 //dd($instituto_id);
$id_alumno = DB::table('alumnos')->where('dni',$dni)->pluck('id')->first();

$doc_faltante = DB::table('doc_insts')
               ->where('instituto_id',$instituto_id)
               ->whereNotIn('doc_insts.id',function ($query) use ($id_alumno, $instituto_id){ //Ver este USE
                   $query->select('documentacion_id')->from('doc_alu_insts')
                         ->where('instituto_id','=', $instituto_id)
                         ->where('alumno_id','=', $id_alumno);
                  })->get();
```